# Looking for a way to automatically resize and skew (perspective) images

Tags: mate, raspberrypi, gimp, image-processing

Today I'm tasked with doing a piece alignment system for a customer.

He needs to align cut pieces (roughly about 50 cm) in a table, so they're processed (table moves after the operator has aligned the piece). How he used to do it is with an overhead laser, but this is a time-consuming task because every time he switches to a new pattern/design he needs to manually re-adjust the lasers. So we're going to replace the overhead lasers with a projector that's powered by a raspberry pi 3 running Ubuntu Mate. This is so that instead of moving the lasers he can just select another image and the projector will instantly change the pattern shown.

The image coming out of the CAD software isn't true to reality due to perspective issues.

I can easily use GIMP in Linux to modify the perspective/scale in order to make it match reality. But here comes the issue, I'm savvy enough to do this, but the customer might not be.

Is there a way for me to "save" these modifications I made to the image in order to make it easier for the customer, so he just needs to "apply" this "filter" to every image he makes to have the same scale/skew changes I did?

**Tl;dr**: I need a way to make a simple "filter" which scales/skews a `.jpg` file in the same way, every time.

Comment: You can [script that in Gimp but it shouldn't be  filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44430081/how-to-run-python-scripts-using-gimpfu-from-windows-command-line/44435560#44435560).   But there is likely a perspective operator in [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) which is more suitable for scripting and headless operation.